# How to specify the libpq correct connection string URL for Unix domain socket connection in the shell?

Tags: postgresql, database-connection, connection-string

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-example.html
compile the 1st example source code.

```
gcc test.c -L/usr/local/pgsql15/lib -I/usr/local/pgsql15/include -lpq
```

Cannot figure out the connection string. All the following failed.

```
./a.out postgresql:///test15?host=/tmp&port=5415
./a.out postgresql://test15?host=/tmp:5415
./a.out postgresql://test15?host=/tmp&port='5415'
./a.out postgresql://test15?host=/tmp:'5415'
./a.out postgresql://test15?host=/tmp&port=/tmp
./a.out postgresql:///tmp:5415/test15?
```

The error is almost similar:

```
connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?

[1]+  Exit 1                  ./a.out postgresql:///test15?host=/tmp
```

`cat  /usr/local/pgsql15/data_42091266/postgresql.conf | rg unix`
return

```
unix_socket_directories = '/tmp'        # comma-separated list of directories
#unix_socket_group = ''                 # (change requires restart)
unix_socket_permissions = 0777          # begin with 0 to use octal notation
```

Comment: Does /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 exist?

Comment: @jjanes it does not. because port is 5415

Comment: The last line of the error message block shows the command that was executed, and it did not give a port.  Probably because the `&` is special to the shell, and ended the command before it got to the port part.  Escape the ampersand.

Comment: @jjanes You are right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [jjanes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1721239/jjanes)
The following two way works.

```
./a.out postgresql:///test15?host=/tmp\&port=5415

./a.out "postgresql:///test15?host=/tmp&port=5415"
```

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.htmlhttps://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html

> Quoting is used to remove the special meaning of certain characters or
> words to the shell. Quoting can be used to preserve the literal
> meaning of the special characters in the next paragraph, prevent
> reserved words from being recognized as such, and prevent parameter
> expansion and command substitution within here-document processing
> (see Here-Document).
>
> The application shall quote the following characters if they are to
> represent themselves:
>
> |  &  ;  <  >  (  )  $  `  \  "  '